# How to design non-required authentication for a public RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, session, authentication

I have two Node servers. One which serves the website, and one which serves the RESTful API which powers the data behind the website.

When the user logs into the website, a session is created. This then allows me to serve the correct HTML to the user depending on whether they are logged in.

My API also needs to identify and authorize users for some endpoints. However, as the API is served on a different server (from the one where the logged in session is created), I cannot re-use that session data. Furthermore, I want the RESTful API to be public, and re-using the session data in this way would possibly prevent that. By public I mean in the long run I would like to allow external developers to interact with and authorise their API requests. Some endpoints need to be authorized (such as `PUT` on the `User` resource), whereas some should be free for all to see (public; such as `GET` on the `User` resource).

This is my first RESTful API and I have never dealt with authentication on this way before. With these specifics in mind, how exactly should I design my authentication layer?

I have a very brief understanding of session tokens and OAuth, but if you have a solution that involves any of these, I would appreciate a detailed explanation of how these things tie together to create the authentication layer. Any links to resources to help me learn various techniques would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as possible you'll want to keep the authentication methods between the two separate. Most calls to the API won't be through the browser and managing sessions in HTTP clients in your code is a huge pain. For the web app that is through the browser, a session-based approach is the right one.

For the API, there's two popular ways to add authentication: HTTP basic auth over SSL and OAuth 2. [I wrote a longer article about how to pick one](http://apiux.com/2013/03/21/authentication-dont-be-clever/). Though for your situation it sounds like simple HTTP basic auth (make sure to use SSL) selectively enabled for specific endpoints is probably the way to go. You could let your users log in with their normal credentials (which the browser will do some caching on and automatically send after the first successful auth for the remainder of the session without using cookies) but I would recommend generating a separate key/token pair for each consumer of the web site. Many popular public APIs that don't use OAuth take this approach (e.g. Twilio).

Answer (score 0):

I will call your webserver A and your dataservice B. A simple scheme would be to register A on B with a private key. Requests from A to B (over https) can then include the Authentication header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header) with the private key, which unlocks the "private" functionality of the API. If called without or with a false private key, these functions will return a HTTP 403 Forbidden or something (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).